# AsyncTask confusion

Tags: android, networking, android-asynctask

I've been trying to program an android that takes allows the user to pull an image off the internet. After publishing this app, i was told by someone, that i need AsyncTask to allow me to use networking commands. Ive been studying the AsycTask page on Android Developers website (developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). This has me completely lost. I have no idea where i need to place this code. Here is my original code that is currently working until published. How can I implement the AsyncTask in here?

CODE:

```
public void firstbutton(View view) 
    {
        InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        inputMgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);

        EditText idnumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String idnumber2= idnumber.getText().toString();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        idnum=i;
        setContentView(R.layout.viewer);
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Drawable image = ImageOperations(context, "HIDDEN FOR PRIVACY"+idnumber2);
        ImageView icon = new ImageView(context);
        icon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        icon.setImageDrawable(image);
};


public Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException
{
URL url = new URL(address);
Object content = url.getContent();
return content;
}
```

LOGCAT FOR TWADDINGTON

```
11-21 20:02:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(343): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-21 20:02:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
11-21 20:02:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-21 20:02:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-21 20:02:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-21 20:02:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-21 20:02:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
11-21 20:02:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
11-21 20:02:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
11-21 20:02:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(343): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;
11-21 20:02:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.phil.avatarview.AvatarViewActivity$FetchImageAsyncTask.doInBackground(AvatarViewActivity.java:1)
11-21 20:02:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-21 20:02:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-21 20:02:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  ... 4 more
11-21 20:02:31.330: I/Process(61): Sending signal. PID: 343 SIG: 3
```

Comment: In the future please make sure your method names start with a lowercase letter. The way you named the `ImageOperations` method makes it look like a class.

Comment: Ok i will make sure to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
/** A custom AsyncTask for downloading images in the background. */
private static class FetchImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Drawable> {
    private final String mUrl;
    private final ImageView mImageView;

    public FetchImageAsyncTask(ImageView view, String url) {
        mUrl = url;
        mImageView = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // This aptly named method will run on a background Thread. This
        // means your user interface will not be interrupted while the
        // image is downloaded.

        try {
            URL url = new URL(mUrl);

            // Instead of URL#getContent() you might consider using the
            // DefaultHttpClient class.
            return Drawable.createFromStream(
                    (InputStream) url.getContent(), "src");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        // The result of doInBackground will be passed to this method, which
        // is run on the UI Thread. This is important because you cannot
        // update an ImageView with a new image from a background Thread.
        if (result != null) {
            mImageView.setImageDrawable(result);
        }
    }
}

public void firstbutton(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    inputMgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);

    EditText idnumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String idnumber2= idnumber.getText().toString();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
    idnum=i;
    setContentView(R.layout.viewer);
    Context context = view.getContext();

    // Get your image view
    ImageView iconView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    // Create a new background task
    FetchImageAsyncTask task = new FetchImageAsyncTask(iconView, "YOUR_URL_HERE");

    // Start the background task
    task.execute();
}
```

Comment: I was trying to use your code but i ran into a problem with the asyncTask manager. Think you can spot what happened?
Heres the LogCat

Comment: I put the logcat in the question. It would not fit here

Comment: Try changing this line `AsyncTask task = ...` to this `FetchImageAsyncTask task = ...`. If that doesn't work please post your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Somethins like this, but I still would recommend (I do it for everybody) look and use only [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) instead. For example [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html)

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable>() {

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
        return ImageOperations(getApplicationContext(), params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ImageView icon = new ImageView(context);
        icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        icon.setImageDrawable(image);
    }
}.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "HIDDEN FOR PRIVACY" + idnumber2);
```

Comment: wouldnt the part that needs the asynctask only the very last part? The fetch method? I thought that was the only networking part? Just wondering and wanting to make sure I dont have to re-ask this question, or do it over and over and still not get it.

Comment: well, I am sure there are a lot of a such questions. Yes, fetch is network IO, that takes time. All IO (in perfect world) you have to run in background thread. But the problem is you need callback once that task is finished to update your UI, otherwise you will just receive Drawable and what you'd do with it?!